# How do I upload XML document to FTP location

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, ftp

I have an XML document. I don't want to save that XML in a physical path. How can I upload to ftp having xml document in memory.

So, i want to know whether it is possible to have an object in memory and save to ftp. I have the code for uploading to ftp which takes local path and        remote path as parameters and upload it.

```
UploadXMLToFTP(XmlDocument xml)

//Now this XMLDocument should be uploaded to ftp without saving in physical drive.
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the [MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx) of how to upload a file via FTP in .NET:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

...
public static void UploadXMLToFTP (XmlDocument xml)
{
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    using(FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm"))
    {
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        request.ContentLength = xml.OuterXml.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        xml.Save(requestStream);
        requestStream.Close();


        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        response.Close();
    }
}
```